# Apache Server Hosting Multiple Sites Using Different Directories (CentOS)

Tags: php, apache, amazon-ec2, centos

Please help me setup correct configuration on apache server. I don't know what it is called but I want to setup multiple sites on my server (Amazon EC2 (CentOS) server). It doesn't have a domain name yet.

I have installed the required software including php (checked with phpinfo.php). It is working fine.

Now, I want to host two different php based sites on my machine. 
Assume, my IP address is **x.y.z.a**

Directories : 
    /var/www/html/crm 
    /var/www/html/crmpanel
    /var/www/html/mysite

In my httpd.conf, I have :
        NameVirtualHost *:80
        ServerName x.y.z.a
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName x.y.z.a
    ServerAlias x.y.z.a

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/crm"

    ErrorLog  /var/log/httpd/error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access_log combined

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName x.y.z.a
    ServerAlias x.y.z.a

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/crmpanel"

    ErrorLog  /var/log/httpd/error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access_log combined

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName x.y.z.a
    ServerAlias x.y.z.a

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/mysite"

    ErrorLog  /var/log/httpd/error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access_log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

If I run "httpd -S", it returns 'Syntax OK'. Apache server starts without any errors.

Please help me understand what is wrong in my configuration.

Comment: I hope you have a different servername in each VirtualHost config. One for site1.com and the other for site2.com

Comment: No, I don't. I have not purchased any domain name yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` **(Domain names instead of the ip)** for corresponding virtual host entry and also the correct `DocumentRoot` .

The ServerAlias is optional .

```
ServerName : xyz.com
ServerAlias  : www.xyz.com
```

please refer this [blog post](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-centos-6) for detailed explanation .

Comment: I suppose DocumentRoot is correctly set, but I don't have any domain names yet. Will it still work if I give any temporary domain names and add the entries to the /etc/hosts file?

Comment: @RiddhishOjha yes it will :) . thats how test the configuration before setting up domains .

Comment: Thanks @SojanVJose, I'll test it and let you know.